# Error :- String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: format

[image]

Please tel me, How to handle this error. :( I've tried so many ways , but none of them could be able to solve it.

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9xk1h71t.aspx)?

Comment: **`June` is only up to `30`** not 31.

Comment: @491243 Good catch! And OP, please next time paste your code as a text, not as an image..

Comment: yep, invalid date "2013/06/31".
Thank you.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and tell me if it works and please change 06/31 to 06/30 june has only 30 days thanks

```
this.Text="30/06/2013";    
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(this.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: The invariant culture is [`CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx) not `CultureInfo.InvariantInfo` ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You have to change `"2013/06/31"` to `"2013/06/30"` since june has only 30 days (as others have already mentioned).

But you also need to use `ParseExact` with `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`. Otherwise your current culture is used to get the date separator which is not necessarily `/`(in many countries it is `.`).

So this [works](http://ideone.com/thQil4) with any culture:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("2013/06/30", "yyyy/MM/dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

[**The "/" Custom Format Specifier**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#dateSeparator)

If you want to validate a given date-string you can use [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/h9b85w22.aspx):

```
DateTime dt; 
if(DateTime.TryParseExact("2013/06/31", "yyyy/MM/dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt)) 
{
    // success, dt contains the correct date now
} 
else 
{
    // not a valid date 
}
```

Comment: @user2549153: Note that you should use `DateTime.TryParseExact` to check if the date is valid. Edited [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18459191/284240) accordingly.